# Powerbuilder - How to create Class Properties

Tags: powerbuilder

How do I create/define properties for a powerbuilder class?  I'm running PowerBuilder 9 and I've been using public variables *like properties* , but I want to know how to create/define PowerBuilder properties for a object.

My guess is that in PB 9, variables/properties are very similar in their usage and implementation.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for in "properties" and, if by "public variables" you mean public-access instance variables, how they fall short. If we understand what you're after, we're more likely to be able to help. (At least *I'm* fuzzy on the concept.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean properties in the way that e.g. C# or PHP defines them, as wrappers for [accessor/mutator methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming)) - something like this (in C#)?

```
class TimePeriod
{
    private double seconds;

    public double Hours
    {
        get { return seconds / 3600; }
        set { seconds = value * 3600; }
    }
}
```

EDIT: As [pointed out by Hugh Brackett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729721/powerbuilder-how-to-create-class-properties/4738176#4738176), this can be done by using the undocumented `INDIRECT` keyword.

The classic (documented) way to do this is to write seperate accessor and mutator methods.  For the example above, you would write some Powerbuilder code like this:

[image: Powerbuilder accessor/mutator code]

(or as source:

```
global type uo_timeperiod from nonvisualobject
end type
global uo_timeperiod uo_timeperiod

type variables
private double id_seconds
end variables

forward prototypes
public function double of_get_hours ()
public subroutine of_set_hours (double ad_seconds)
end prototypes

public function double of_get_hours ();
return id_seconds / 3600
end function

public subroutine of_set_hours (double ad_seconds);
id_seconds = ad_seconds * 3600
end subroutine
```

)

Answer (score 5):

You can create properties with the undocumented `indirect` keyword.
Here's an [article that explains how to use the indirect keyword in PowerBuilder](http://www.rgagnon.com/pbdetails/pb-0133.html)
The normal caution about using undocumented features applies.